# React-How to get blob SAS URL or SAS token?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a react app written in typescrpt in which i'm getting document name as a query parameter.I wanted to get the SAS url of this document to do further processing . Please suggest any approach.

Thank you!

Note:My app is not ad authenticated.

Answer (score -1):

The SAS token is something that you first need to create and then fetch to your app. For example in a project I'm working right now for every blob I receive from a container I programmatically create a SAS token and append it to the URL of the same blob. Or you can create a container level token which you can append to every blob's URL in your container.

In this link you will find how to create tokens -container and blob level- programmatically.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-service-sas-create-dotnet?tabs=dotnet#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob-container

Comment: This isn't a great answer for the question.  React cannot use the SharedKeyCredential that is required